# Blender 3.3 Materials Misaligned

Tags: materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to map out the texture for this stage, but for some reason the material is not aligning properly at all. When I attempt to move the UV islands the texture doesn't change on the live preview at all, its as if the models are using a separate map than what's presented. I'm more of a Blender 2.79 user on the whole, and I haven't come across an issue like this before. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks!

[image: Blender Material Misalignment]

Comment: Check the Properties panel >Object Data > UV Maps, have you created a second UV Map?

Comment: OK I had no idea that was even a thing! You are a lifesaver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Properties panel >Object Data > UV Maps*, you have created a second UV map, remove it